# Are there any advantages in using const parameters with an ordinal type?

Tags: delphi

I know marking string parameters as `const` can make a huge performance difference, but what about ordinal types? Do I gain anything by making them `const`?

I've always used `const` parameters when handling strings, but never for `Integer`, `Pointer`, class instances, etc.

When using `const` I often have to create additional temporary variables, which replace the now write-protected parameters, so I'm wondering: Do I gain anything from marking ordinal parameters as `const`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to understand the reason, to avoid "cargo-cult programming."  Marking strings as const makes a performance difference because you no longer need to use an interlocked increment and decrement of the refcount on the string, an operation that *actually becomes more expensive, not less, as time goes by* because more cores means more work that has to be done to keep atomic operations in sync.  This is safe to do since the compiler enforces the "this variable will not be changed" constraint.

For ordinals, which are usually 4 bytes or less, there's no performance gain to be had.  Using **const** as optimization only works when you're using value types that are larger than 4 bytes, such as arrays or records, or reference-counted types such as strings and interfaces.

However, there's another important advantage: code readability.  If you pass something as **const** and it makes no difference whatsoever to the compiler, it can still make a difference to *you*, since you can read the code and see that the intention of it was to have this not be modified.  That can be significant if you haven't seen the code before (someone else wrote it) or if you're coming back to it after a long time and don't remember exactly what you were thinking when you originally wrote it.

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong regarding strings. Strings are always passed as their four-byte pointer representation. `Const` suppresses the code in the function's prologue and epilogue that updates the string's reference count. The same goes for interface parameters and dynamic arrays. Likewise, records are passed as pointers. `Const` merely suppresses the prologue code that copies the record onto the function's local stack. In other words, `const` has *no effect* on the *caller* side of a function. It only affects the receiver of the call.

Comment: @Rob: Bummer that comments cannot be edited. It's easy to misread your comment as if you're saying that records are always passed as pointers.

Comment: If that's what you think I said, then you did not misread anything, Wouter. Records that are larger than a pointer *are* always passed as pointers. The caller places a pointer on the stack. If the parameter is not const, then the *receiver* of the call makes a copy of the record. It's the same as with strings. The caller passes a pointer, and the receiver makes a copy. In the case of strings, making a copy is simply updating the reference count, though.

Comment: Using `const` with strings does **not** prevent a copy!! Using `const` only prevents an increase of the reference count as well as an implicit `try..finally` block. The `try..finally` is somewhat expensive, but nowhere near as expensive as a copy can be.

Comment: Wow, did I really write that?  Derp... OK, fixed now.

Comment: Would be nice to extend the answer with information about ordinal types that are larger than 4 bytes (eg. Extended or Int64). Are there differences between Win32 and Win64 project targets?

Answer (score 17):

You can't accidentally treat them like `var` parameters and have your code compile. So it makes your intentions clear.

Comment: Good point, but isn't it enough to NOT specify a parameter var to make one's intention clear?

Comment: Smasher, the compiler doesn't distinguish between var and the default convention insofar as what you are allowed to do with the argument in the method.

Comment: Even if it seems clear at the moment that this is a value you don't intend to change, it might not six months later when you come back to it, or when a maintenance programmer has to look at your code.

Comment: Mason, that's exactly my point. To get the maintainer's mind into the same mindset as the creator's mind. The maintainer can change the convention if need be, but she should understand the intention of the creator.

Comment: Yeah.  I should have probably put an @Smasher in front of that last comment. :p

Answer (score 7):

Declaring ordinal types const makes no difference because they are copied anyway (call-by-value), so any changes to the variable do not affect the original variable.

```
procedure Foo (Val : Integer)
begin
Val := 2;
end;
...
SomeVar := 3;
Foo (SomeVar);
Assert (SomeVar = 3);
```

IMHO declaring ordinal types const makes no sense and as you say requires you to introduce local variables often.

Comment: Craig has a valid point.  There is a good reason to declare an ordinal as const; just not for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how complex is your routine and how it is used. If it is used many places and required that the value stay the same, declare it as "const" to make it cleared and safe. For string type, there was a bug (for Delphi 7 as I stump on it) that causes memory corruption if declare as "const". Below is sample codes

```
type
  TFoo = class 
  private
     FStr: string;
  public
     procedure DoFoo(const AStr: string);
     begin
        FStr := AStr; //the trouble code 1
        ......
     end;
     procedure DoFoo2;
     begin
        .....
        DoFoo(FStr);  //the trouble code 2
     end;
  end;
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a huge speed improvement using Const with strings:

```
function test(k: string): string;
begin
  Result := k;
end;

function test2(Const k: string): string;
begin
  Result := k;
end;

function test3(Var k: string): string;
begin
  Result := k;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var a: Integer;
    s,b: string;
    x: Int64;
begin
  s := 'jkdfjklf lkjj3i2ej39ijkl  jkl2eje23 io3je32 e832 eu283 89389e3jio3 j938j 839 d983j9';

  PerfTimerInit;
  for a := 1 to 10000000 do
   b := test(s);
  x := PerfTimerStopMS;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('default: '+x.ToString);

  PerfTimerInit;
  for a := 1 to 10000000 do
   b := test2(s);
  x := PerfTimerStopMS;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('const: '+x.ToString);

  PerfTimerInit;
  for a := 1 to 10000000 do
   b := test3(s);
  x := PerfTimerStopMS;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('var: '+x.ToString);
end;
```

> default: 443 const: 320 var: 325
>
> default: 444 const: 303 var: 310
>
> default: 444 const: 302 var: 305

Same with Integers:

> default: 142 const: 13 var: 14

Interestingly though, in 64-bit there seems to be almost no difference with strings (default mode is only a bit slower than Const):

> default: 352 const: 313 var: 314