# What difference does it make when I use "const" in a procedure's parameter?

Tags: delphi, parameters, constants

What difference does it make when I use a `const` parameter in a procedure?

Take the following procedure for example:

```
procedure DoSomething(Sender: TObject; const Text: String; var Reply: String);
begin
  //Text is read-only and Reply will be passed back wherever DoSomething() was called
  Reply:= Text;
end;
```

The parameter `Text: String` is prefixed with `const` so that (as far as I know), a copy of the value is made and used - and is read-only. What I was wondering is how is does this affect the application any differently than if I didn't put `const` there? Perhaps a performance trick?

Comment: Answered here?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1601124/496736

Comment: In most cases, I think the major benefit of carefully marking all input-only parameters as `const` is that you, the programmer, will get an additional help avoiding silly bugs.

Comment: @Andreas What's galling is that the `const` needs to be included in both interface and implementation. This is one area where C++ beats Delphi.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Although a more-so opinionated comment, I actually find that to be the most reasonable answer. Makes tons of sense, it practically just makes it read-only so that whoever's implementing that procedure can't even attempt to assign that value. However at the same time, I've seen people use arguments which aren't prefixed with anything and temporarily assign a new value to it, knowing that the new value won't be passed back as if it were a `var` parameter.

Comment: @JerryDodge I just added an example to my answer to show you a successful attempt to assign a const parameter ;) Actually its more of a proof to show that the compiler creates a pass by reference internally while making sure "normal" assigning does not work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Constant_Parameters) states:

"Using const allows the compiler to optimize code for structured - and string-type parameters. It also provides a safeguard against unintentionally passing a parameter by reference to another routine."

In case of a string for example the optimization means there is no additional refcounting when passing as const. Also passing as const does **not** mean it's a copy. Often it internally passes as reference because the compiler ensures no write access to it.

Some very interesting articles to completly understand what's going on under the hood:

http://delphitools.info/2010/07/28/all-hail-the-const-parameters

http://vcldeveloper.com/articles/different-function-parameter-modifiers-in-delphi

Edit:

A simple example to show that const may result in pass by reference internally:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;
  TMyRecord = record
    Value1: Cardinal;
    Value2: Cardinal;
  end;

procedure PassAsConst(const r: TMyRecord);
begin
  PMyRecord(@r).Value1 := 3333;
  PMyRecord(@r).Value2 := 4444;
end;

procedure PassByVal(r: TMyRecord);
begin
  PMyRecord(@r).Value1 := 3333;
  PMyRecord(@r).Value2 := 4444;
end;

var
  r: TMyRecord;
begin
  r.Value1 := 1111;
  r.Value2 := 2222;
  PassByVal(r);
  Writeln(r.Value1);
  Writeln(r.Value2);

  PassAsConst(r);
  Writeln(r.Value1);
  Writeln(r.Value2);

  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: FWIW: for how it is **passed**, it doesn't matter if a parameter is const or not. If it is not explicitly declared `var` or `out`, it will be **passed** the same for const or non-const. Generally, items larger than register size (say, 32 bit) will be **passed** by reference, no matter if they are const or not. The only difference between const and non-const is that for non-const, hidden code is inserted at the start that copies the item to local storage. For const, only reading references are allowed, so this copying code is missing and the passed reference is used directly.

Answer (score 10):

When you don't have the const prefix, the compiler has to assume that you will be changing the parameter. That means copying it and setting up a hidden try...finally to dispose of the local string variable, so sometimes the const can yield a significant performance improvement. It also makes the generated code smaller.

Comment: I should add that this is true as of Delphi 2007 - the newest I have installed. I more advanced compiler could potentially detect that a parameter wasn't in fact being used as a variable even without the const prefix and not copy it, but those types of optimizations have historically not been the focus of the Delphi R&D team.

Comment: It is true in all versions of Delphi that know const parameters, i.e. well before D2007: No need to copy structures, if they were passed by reference (this depends on their size), to local storage and no need to do reference counting.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers of efficiency when using a const (i.e. the compiler does not need to copy the variable), if you use a const with an Interface parameter, it prevents the triggering of ref counting.

Comment: Which is the reason for this behaviour: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=75036

Comment: The lack of reference-counting is the same for interfaces and strings. What you've said about interfaces isn't "in addition to" the stuff about strings. The *variable* gets copied all the time, but copying those is cheap since it's just copying the value of a pointer, which is sometimes no more than copying a value form one register to another.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `const string` parameter in your function it is your promise to Delphi compiler that you would not call any other function from it, at least not before you made copies of all those `const string` parameters into local variables you would have for them.

https://github.com/the-Arioch/XE2_AutoOpenUnit/blob/master/Delphi_String_Bug/Girli_str_2xFree_Minimized.dpr

https://plus.google.com/+AriochThe/posts/WB3toSpAdfA

```
program Girli_str_2xFree_Minimized;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

// initial mini-demo by Ãèðëèîíàéëüäî - http://www.sql.ru/forum/memberinfo.aspx?mid=249076
// variance IfDef's re-added by Arioch (orginal reporter)

uses
  SysUtils;

{.$Define TestBug_Impl_Exit}
{.$Define TestBug_Impl_AsIs}

{.$Define NewStr_Unique}

var
  rFile: string; 
// global or local does not matter.
// originally it was an object member.

{$IfNDef TestBug_Impl_Exit} {$IfNDef TestBug_Impl_AsIs}
function TestBUG(const S: string): string;
begin
  Result := S;
end;
{$EndIf}{$EndIf}

{$IfDef TestBug_Impl_AsIs}
procedure TestBUG(const S: string; var Result: string);
begin
  Result := S;
end;
{$EndIf}

{$IfDef TestBug_Impl_Exit}
function TestBUG(const S: string): string;
begin
  Exit(S);
end;
{$EndIf}

procedure Test(const FileName: string);
{$IfDef TestBug_Impl_AsIs} var unnamed_temp: string; {$EndIf}
begin

// rFile := FileName.SubString(0, Length(FileName));  // unavail in XE2

{$IfNDef NewStr_Unique}
  rFile := Copy(FileName, 1, Length(FileName));
  // reference-counting broken, de facto writes into const-string (destroys it)
{$Else}
  rFile := FileName; // no bug, reference-counting proceeded normally!
  UniqueString(rFile);
{$EndIf}

{$IfNDef TestBug_Impl_AsIs}
  TestBUG(FileName); // try to use the const-pointer to the old string
{$Else}
  TestBUG(FileName, unnamed_temp);
{$EndIf}
end; // <== Fatality here

begin
  try
    try
      rFile := ParamStr(0);
      Test(rFile);

      Writeln('Safely returned from the hazardous function without memory dislocations.');

    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Writeln;
    Writeln('Read the output. Press ENTER to terminate the program.');
    Readln;
  end;
end.
```

Since volatile string and const string are de facto two different types - the classic compiler treats them differently - there should had been data conversion added: when calling const-string function passing it volatile-string parameters Delphi could had increment the use counter and decrease it after function exit. Passing const-strings parameters down the line into next const-string function would be just how it is now, once compiler typecasted volatile string into const string it can remain so.

Sadly, it does not. And here be dragons.

So, if your function has const string parameters - either do not call from it or cache those parameters into local vars.