# Is passing a DLL function argument with "const" an equivalent to pointer?

Tags: delphi, dll, pass-by-reference, calling-convention, stdcall

Data block:

```
PMyDataBlock = ^MyDataBlock;
MyDataBlock = record
  // .............
end;
```

Is a following definition:

```
function MyFunction(const pstSettings: MyDataBlock): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'MyLib.dll' name 'MyFunction';
```

a full equivalent of this?:

```
function MyFunction(pstSettings: PMyDataBlock): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'MyLib.dll' name 'MyFunction';
```

Comment: `const` implies special semantics for Delphi compiler only. I wouldn't use it in external function declaration. And, no, it's not equivalent to pointer. That depends on the type of the argument. E.g. `const Integer` is not `PInteger`, but there are more ...

Comment: See also [What difference does it make when I use “const” in a procedure's parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001477/what-difference-does-it-make-when-i-use-const-in-a-procedures-parameter).

Comment: Peter Wolf, the external function is already declared and is written in C.

Comment: I meant external function declaration in your *Delphi* code (where you refer to a function in DLL).

Comment: Ok, then I'll stick with pointers. In this case I can even pass a NIL argument.

Comment: Since Delphi 10.4 you can force the compiler to pass a [constant parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Constant_Parameters) by reference using `[Ref]` decorator. You should be still able to pass `nil` using `PMyDataBlock(nil)^`, although I didn't experiment with that. I still don't recommend using it in external functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No, it is not"

In your case, your record may or may not be passed by reference. The size of the record is 1 of the factor I know of that affect that behavior. If your record is 4 bytes or less, I believe it will be passed by value, otherwise, it will be passed by reference. I don't believe this behavior is contractual (In other word, Embarcadero is free to change it at any time in the future). In other words, it's a bad idea to use const parameter to call an external function.

If you want to pass your record by reference, the proper way to do would be to declare it **`var`**

```
function MyFunction(var pstSettings: MyDataBlock): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'MyLib.dll' name 'MyFunction';
```

or pass it as a pointer.

Comment: A const record size smaller or equal to the size of a pointer, means that the compiler is free to pass it by value. Unless you use the [ref] decorator introduced in recent Delphi versions.