# TList of const interface pointers

Tags: object, delphi, interface, constants, containers

I had class field

```
someList : TList<SomeInterFace>;
```

I need only to store objects inside the list and search for them, never want to modify. So i decided to write

```
someList : TList<const SomeInterFace>;
```

But I have lots of compiler error. It seems not possible to store const objects in standard Delphi containers?

Comment: You never want to modify what... the content of the list or the content of the objects? Also interface references lifetime is handled through reference counting. `const`  is applicable for interface references only when they are passed as parameters, and it is used as signal to the compiler not to trigger reference counting mechanism for that parameter. Are you trying to store weak interface references in the list?

Answer (score 2):

`const` only makes sense in the context of a method :

```
procedure DoSomethingWithInterface(const AInterface: SomeInterface)
begin
  // do something
end;
```

Here, without the `const` declaration the interfaces's reference count is incremented when it is passed into the method and it is decremented again when the method returns.  Using `const` the interface is passed by reference but the reference count *is not modified*.  This works because there is no way that the interface's reference count can go down while you're still inside the method so the program can treat this temporary usage inside the method as though it didn't happen, saving the overhead of having to modify the reference count field.  More reading on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11001477/327083).

Storing a reference in a list, however, is a different matter altogether since the lifetime of the object in the list is indeterminate. A method has a clear start and end so the duration that you hold onto a reference to the object is strictly limited - there is no risk that the object would be deleted (notwithstanding cross-thread operations on shared variables or other such concurrency bugs) while you were still using it. In a list, though, there are no guarantees about how long that reference will live in the list so you cannot bypass incrementing the reference count.

Furthermore, the big savings using `const` in a method is that the compiler generates an implicit `try`/`finally` block around the method otherwise to manage the reference count.  Using `const` in a method allows you to save the overhead of that try/finally, which is the major performance gain.  When adding a string or interface reference to a list, though, there is no such implicit code generated since you, the developer, are in complete control of the lifetime of the reference in the list, unlike the argument passed into a method, which the *compiler* has to manage.

So, in summary, no there is no way to do what you propose, but there is also no *need* to do what you propose. If you bypassed reference counting for interface references in your list then the objects they point to could be deleted any time the rest of the references to them went away and you would end up with a dead reference in your list.

Comment: Remy is right: Strings use "copy on write" (COW) semantics.