# const for every params, good or not

Tags: delphi

With the arc, i realize that i put often all the params of my procedure/function as const because on arc, without const you will have a refcount increase/decrease on the object, like on string.

exemple :

```
procedure xxx(const a: Tobject;
              const b: integer;
              const c: string;
              const anything: anything);
```

but i ask myself, for Tobject and string it's seam pertinant to do so, but for integer and other, is this slowing anything somewhere ? is it just at compilation time that the compiler check we don't update the const variable ?

Comment: It's interesting that you say "for `TObject` it seems pertinent to do so". That's probably the least useful parameter to declare as **const**. In Delphi, objects are always passed by reference, so there's no performance benefit. Furthermore **const** might create the false impression that the object passed in cannot be changed. That's incorrect, because nothing prevents the implementation from calling state altering methods on the object.

Comment: @Craig: loki seems to be programming for Android, most of the time. Since object references are reference counted there, it may make sense to use `const`, for performance reasons, i.e. the same reasons you use it for e.g. interfaces or strings.

Comment: @Rudy In that case, yes it has the same level of justification as **string**. Personally I've grown to like that C++ has a mechanism to prevent calling state altering methods on objects passed as **const**.

Comment: And as of enhanced records even const value types can be modified by evil state mutating methods.

Comment: @CraigYoung yes off course i work under nextgen and this mean object are reference counted. anyway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600991/are-there-any-advantages-in-using-const-parameters-with-an-ordinal-type answer perfectly my question, i didn't see this thread before to post

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ... about record yes i saw also that for example when you pass const aRect: Trectf (for exemple) and then inside the function you do something like aRect.top := xxx (you can do it) and worse this will be applyied to the original rect you pass to the function :( i think this is maybe a bug

Comment: @loki: What David means is that records with methods can alter "themselves", in those methods. So while you can't modify the members of a const parameter directly, they can still be modified (inadvertently) by calling the methods of the const record, if these methods modify internal state. It takes some care to give such records an immutable interface.

Comment: Thanks for that @David I was actually planning to test it for myself.