# Is there some advantage in passing a Char parameter as "const"?

Tags: delphi, parameters, parameter-passing, delphi-xe7

I've [read](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Constant_Parameters) that passing parameters as `const` allows the compiler to optimize code for structured and string types.

Is there some advantage in declaring a `Char` parameter as `const`?

```
procedure Test(const AMyChar : Char);
```

instead of

```
procedure Test(AMyChar : Char);
```

And if so, does it have something to do with the [unicode migration](https://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/delphi-unicode-migration.pdf)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any advantages in using const parameters with an ordinal type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600991/are-there-any-advantages-in-using-const-parameters-with-an-ordinal-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some advantage in declaring a Char parameter as const?

No, it makes no difference to how the value is passed.

What you are referring to is an optimisation for passing reference counted types. When they are passed as `const` the compiler can omit reference counting code because it knows the callee can't modify the object. But `Char` is not reference counted and so that does not apply.

Or that structured types can be passed by reference rather than by copy if `const` is used. That can avoid some memory copying which can have performance benefits for larger types. Again that does not apply to 16 bit `Char`.

Think of `Char` as an integer type when you want to reason about how it is passed to functions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. And what about the `Variant` type parameters?

Comment: Definitely more efficient to pass as `const`