# Should I pass a parameter as a const in a function if I don't intend to modify it?

Tags: delphi, parameters, readonly-variable

When I'm writing functions, I rarely add the `const` keyword to my params regardless of whether I intend to modify the params or not. This is just due to habit from when I was a beginner in Delphi and not knowing about the `const` keyword. But, it's the same for my company's entire Delphi codebase as well: we rarely pass constant parameters to functions and procedures.

So, now I'm wondering whether we should update our entire codebase and actually be adding the `const` keyboard if we don't intend to modify the parameters in any way.

I'm wondering things like:

1. Is it good practice to use `const` for parameters that won’t be modified?
2. Does marking a parameter as `const` have any impact on performance or code optimization?
3. Are there any potential pitfalls or scenarios where using `const` might lead to unexpected behaviour?
4. Are there cases in which it is better not to use `const` even if you aren't modifying the param?

In my brain, I'm thinking I should always be using `const` if I'm not changing the values... but currently, I never use `const`.

Comment: This has been discussed quite a few times before, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001477/what-difference-does-it-make-when-i-use-const-in-a-procedures-parameter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600991/are-there-any-advantages-in-using-const-parameters-with-an-ordinal-type/1601124#1601124

Comment: In brief: (1) Subjective, but mostly "yes". (2) Yes, for example for `string` parameters. (In 99.99% of all cases, though, you will not notice the difference.) (3) No, not normally.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks for the info and link to the other post. It definitely gave me some clarity. The answers on the other post doesn't properly answer all the things I'm wondering about it though, but would you say this question is a duplicate then and I should delete it? Or should I keep it for new answers?

Comment: I think it is very close to a duplicate, but if you like you can leave it here and see if someone wants to write a more complete answer.

Comment: In Delphi 7 I experienced odd things if I'd use `const` on everything - seems like it's [a bug on `String` parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602086/4299358).

Comment: I seem to remember that using const with Interface types can wreak havoc with reference counting under some circumstances. But my memory is rather sketchy.

Comment: @dummzeuch the problem with using `const` on an interface parameter is if you construct an interfaced object directly in the parameter, eg: `someProc(TIntfObject.Create)` then the object will either be leaked, or worse destroyed prematurely if the proc passes it around to other things that do refcount it. You would need to use `someProc(TIntfObject.Create as Intf)` to avoid that.